# Setting ELB IP address for outbound UDP traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

**Setup:** Multiple EC2 servers running behind an ELB. The "elastic" IP address associated with the ELB receives the UDP traffic and passes to an EC2 instance. An API adds items to an SQS, which the EC2 pull from the Queue and trigger outbound UDP messages.

**Problem:** The solution requires that the Inbound IP address and outbound IP address be the same. The traffic is UDP, and the outbound traffic is triggered by the EC2 pulling data off an SQS. Currently, the outbound traffic is the instances IP, and I need the traffic originating from the EC2 instance to have the same IP as the inbound traffic(to the ELB).

I don't think I can accomplish this with an ELB alone, and I'm looking for solutions that I can use to achieve this.

Any directions would be helpful.

Comment: It's unlikely that you can do this, at all, because of the way cloud networking works. (It looks like Ethernet, but isn't, and forging traffic is impossible.) But if you could tolerate traffic coming in on address A but leaving with source address B (a single IP for the cluster, but a different IP than inbound) then a NAT Gateway could potentially serve that purpose, for UDP.

Comment: yea your spot on on the forging bit :(

Comment: I am not sure but take a look at AWS Global Accelerator. This service provides 2 static IP addresses for you and you can use these 2 IP addresses with TCP and UDP. This service is for High Availability. But it can solve your problem.

Comment: @emert117 I checked out the Accelerator, and I do not see much that makes me think that could work. Mainly this is for routing inbound traffic, so like the ELB there's not much if any outbound controls. Did you know of some feature specifically that makes you think this could work?